# Guidance needed in determining where to post a general, but developer specific, Android question

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, cross-posting

As of late (specifically the release of Android 4.2 handsets), I have noticed more and more Android Apps updating with one particular permission change:

[image: New permission cropping up in many Android app updates]

I'd like some understanding whether this is just Android developers being lazy programmers, Google having changed something in Android 4.2 where apps are getting killed too aggressively and Android developers have no other choice?

My concern is, I don't want to write up a post detailing my question just to have it closed and then not being able or feeling comfortable posting elsewhere (cross-posting = bad) as it would have just been migrated if mods felt it belonged somewhere else.

So, my question:

Where does a question like this belong? I feel Android Enthusiasts will just say "yeah I've seen the same thing" and although I feel I need the opinions of developers who have experience I don't want SO members to just bash it being too open ended and I definitely wouldn't want it to spur debate, I am looking for a real answer.

Comment: You could always try an Android related chat room.

Comment: Very true, thanks. Any suggestions? The SO Android chat is always pretty quiet. Should I just get geeky and search out any Android Developer IRC's?

Comment: Thanks @Yannis I was looking for a tag like that. good to know

Comment: @Bart do you mean to say a question like this really doesn't belong in Stack Exchange community?

Comment: As currently written, this wouldn't be a great fit for SO, and probably wouldn't fit into the Android site either.  However, it's still relevant to developers, which is why asking it in a chat could work out for you.  Maybe if you ask it like "what is this new permission called, what API version was it introduced in, and why do so many apps suddenly ask for it by default" might be something answerable.

Comment: @TryTryAgain I don't think the question as outlined is a good one for SO indeed. But if you can formulate it properly, by all means go ahead. I don't myself participate in many chatrooms on SO, but assumed there must be an Android one. If this isn't active (enough) that's unfortunate, but I don't have particular other suggestions.

Comment: A great question. I've had the same problem: where can I ask a question that I need answered by other developers but is not strictly a programming question? Wish I had the answer. Although in this particular case, you can probably make it programming related so it is suitable on SO. You could ask what causes the permission to be displayed and what functions the wake lock serves, then try to guide the comments on why it is appearing more.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will reformulate the question after doing some testing and building some test apps to see what's really going on; then outline it so it fits for SO.